# Define query in Express calls

Tags: node.js, express

I know how to define params in routes

```
app.get('/:someParams', () => {})
```

How do I expcitily define a query in routes? e.g. adding '?someQuery',
make that query as required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short: You can't.

For route matching Express uses the module `path-to-regexp` which does not support matching on an URLs query. You will have to do that check in your route's handler:

```
app.get('/home', (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.query.foo) {
    handleFooRequest(req, res, next);
  } else {
    handleBarRequest(req, res, next);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Express.js when matching routes skips the query string. If you want more fine detail definition of the url to match with some variable params you can define an endpoint like:

```
app.get('/api/library/:foo/book/:bar', () => {
  const { foo, bar } = req.params;
  ...
});
```

This could be an equivalent to routes formed such `/api?library=1&book=2` but instead being used with query string you can use query params and it would result in this route: `/api/library/1/book/2`.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to use query, cause it makes more sense

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling `req.params` to get the value of the request parameter, you can use `req.query`. This will allow you to
filter your data based on the query string that gets passed. In Express, the query param is based on a key-value pair that depends
on how you have your data layer structured.

For example, if you have a REST API with an endpoint `/products` and data stored in the form:

```
{
    name: "PRODUCT NAME"
    brand: "PRODUCT BRAND"
    price: "PRICE"
    ...
}
```

Then you can do something like `/products?brand=apple` to only return apple products. Obviously then in you Express method handling the `/products` route you will have the logic to filter by the key passed.

A more in depth  explination can be found [here](https://coursework.vschool.io/express-params-and-query/).

Hope it helped

Comment: Thanks, but my question is how to explicitly define query on routes.